# What is the best way to create animations with x3Dom?

Tags: javascript, x3d, x3dom

I want to build a scene that has some animations that are toggled by a checkbox. When clicked I want the height of all box elements to scale to '.1'. When clicked again I want it to return to the original height. I have experimented with Routes and TimeSensors but have found them difficult to work with. Are there any simpler options for animating in x3dom?

Here is some code I have used in my template

```
<timeSensor DEF="time" cycleInterval="2" loop="false" > </timeSensor>
<positionInterpolator def="scale" key="0 1" keyValue="1 1 1  1 .1" ></positionInterpolator>
<route fromNode="time" fromField ="fraction_changed" toNode="scale" toField="set_fraction"></route> 
<route fromNode="scale" fromField ="value_changed" toNode="box" toField="size"></route>
```

Comment: Interpolators + Routes / 
JavaScript

Comment: So you can use routes without the timeSensor? I was using a positionInterpolator along with routes and a timeSensor to modify the scale of my box but it was a little wacky and inconsistent. Could you give an example of how to use interpolators without the timeSenor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the TimeSensor is mandatory because he's the one triggering the keyValue of an interpolator.
Here's a simple example, the TimeSensor is very easy to use:

> DEF TS TimeSensor {    cycleInterval 2    loop TRUE   }
>   DEF SI
>   ScalarInterpolator {
>   key [0 0.5 1]
>   keyValue
>   [2 2 2 1 1 1 0.5 0.5 0.5]   }
>
> ROUTE TS.fraction_changed TO SI.set_fraction
>   ROUTE SI.value_changed TO
>   BOX.scale

The fraction of the timer is routed to the ScalarInterpolator. Whenever the fraction is bigger than a value in the key (0, 0.5 or 1) the corresponding keyValue (the Nth index) is routed to the scale of the BOX. That's it...

If you want to have a slower effect you can increase the cycle interval of the TimeSensor. If you want to have the effect just once then you can set the loop to FALSE.

Also you can have multiple key & keyValues..

Comment: A couple questions. I want the effect to be done multiple times bound to a checkbox. Do i set the loop attribute to false or true? I was experimenting with changing the loop attribute but I would get weird issues. Another thing. I am using this in conjunction with Backbone/Marionette. I will have multiple boxes. Is there a way to bind one route to all Boxes? Thank you so much for helping me! I'm going to edit my question to include some more examples of what I have done

Comment: Actually on a another review of my code I think the issue has to deal with backbone and not necessarily the interpolators. The way I capture model events and changes is interfering with my translations and scales. Thanks for all the help though.

Comment: If the loop is TRUE then the scaling effect will be performed automatically as long as the "active" field is TRUE. If you want to bound the effect to a checkbox then you can set the "active" field (TRUE) only when the checkbox is checked. Once you uncheck it, the "active" field is deactivated (FALSE)

Comment: Right the issue just becomes that if the checkbox is true I only want the effect to last one time not loop. I want it the checkbox to change the scale and simply transition the scale. If loop is set to true it will repeat the effect.

Comment: Exactly. Therefore you need the TimeSensor's loop field to be FALSE :)